# Optimize JS animation in React

Tags: reactjs, animation

I'm currently trying to optimize the animation component. Can you advise if there are any things I might be overlooking or doing wrong?

I still feel like there are screen jitters/freezes, even though I'm on a Mac M2, and my FPS is almost always at 60. Despite this, I still notice some jerks when scrolling.

Here's my component for example:

```
import React, { CSSProperties, useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

import { debounce } from '@/components/effects/anmt';
import { FadeInProps } from '@/components/effects/anmt/types';
import { useVisible } from '@/components/effects/anmt/utils/useVisible';

const FadeIn: React.FC<FadeInProps> = ({
    children,
    duration = 0.5,
    maxTranslate = 50,
    trigger = 0.2,
}: FadeInProps) => {
    const ref = useRef<HTMLElement>(null);
    const visible = useVisible(ref);

    const handleAnimation = () => {
        const element = ref.current;

        if (!visible || !element) {
            return;
        }

        const { top } = element.getBoundingClientRect();
        const actionPoint = element.offsetHeight * trigger;
        const elementTop = top + window.scrollY - actionPoint;
        const translateX =
            window.innerHeight - element.offsetHeight + window.scrollY;
        const transition = Math.max(
            0,
            Math.min(elementTop - translateX, maxTranslate)
        );
        const opacity = 1 - transition / maxTranslate;

        element.style.opacity = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, opacity)).toString();
    };

    const debouncedAnimation = debounce(handleAnimation, 8);

    const requestAnimation = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(debouncedAnimation);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        debouncedAnimation();
        window.addEventListener('scroll', requestAnimation);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', requestAnimation);
        };
    }, [visible]);

    const style: CSSProperties = {
        transition: `opacity ${duration}s linear`,
    };

    return React.cloneElement(
        React.Children.only(children) as React.ReactElement,
        {
            ref,
            style,
        }
    );
};

export { FadeIn };
```

```
export const debounce = (func: Function, delay: number) => {
    let timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout>;

    return (...args: any[]) => {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
        timeoutId = setTimeout(() => func(...args), delay);
    };
};
```

```
import { RefObject, useEffect, useState } from 'react';

export const useVisible = (ref: RefObject<HTMLElement | null>): boolean => {
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const element = ref.current;

        const handleIntersection = (entries: IntersectionObserverEntry[]) => {
            const [entry] = entries;
            setVisible(() => entry.isIntersecting);
        };

        if (element) {
            const observer = new IntersectionObserver(handleIntersection, {
                root: null,
                rootMargin: '0px',
                threshold: 0,
            });

            observer.observe(element);

            return () => {
                observer.disconnect();
            };
        }
    }, [ref]);

    return visible;
};
```

I'm using debounce to reduce the number of calls, as well as requestAnimationFrame for optimization. Additionally, I've created a custom hook that utilizes IntersectionObserver to determine the visibility of the element.